# jQuery preventDefault not working in any IE version

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, preventdefault

I'm tring to prevent users entering any more input into a textarea when the char count reaches a certain value.

My code works fine in Chrome, Safarai and Firefox.

But the ***preventDefault*** method will *not work* for me in any version of ***IE***.

I have found many similar topics on SO about this and included the most common suggestion:

- Performing a check to make sure preventDefault exists. If it doesn not exist use IEs ***returnValue=false***. The problem is ***returnValue=false*** will not work either.

Any suggestions?

```
// Attach textarea char counter to all textarea's with class of 'textarea-char-count'
$('.textarea-char-count').live("keyup", function(event) {
    MYAPP.COMMON.textareaCounter(this, event);
}); 

// Attach textarea char counter to element
MYAPP.COMMON.textareaCounter = function(element, evt) {

    //Get char limit
    var limit = $(element).attr("maxlength");

    // get current character count
    var current = $(element).val().length;

    // if current character count is greater than or equal to the character limit
    if(current >= limit) {
        // prevent further characters from being entered apart from the 
        // Delete and Backspace keys
        if(evt.which != 0 && evt.which != 8)
        {
            if (evt.preventDefault) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                evt.returnValue = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // add the remaining character count to our span
    $(element).parent().next().show().text( current + " / " +  limit);
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE and which version of jQuery? It works for me in IE 8 and 9

Comment: try use stopPropagation() also update your jquery lib file...

Comment: @s.lenders - All versions of IE for me and jQuery1.7.2

Comment: Indeed try using the latest jQuery. And all version, i will add that anything from 7 and below is out of date and shouldn't be used. So if it doesn't work in 8+ then ok.

Comment: @s.lenders: Not everyone can put such restrictions on which browsers to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the event from `keyup` to `keydown`, it will work

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73EsY/) with keyup

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/73EsY/10/) with keydown

The keypress event will not work [since IE and Chrome does not fire it on backspace and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418562/why-isnt-backspace-being-detected-using-jquery-keypress-event)

Note: The counter still behave oddly.

There are some more changes that can be done, ex move from `live` to `on` since `live` is deprecated

Comment: Any ideas why keydown works and keyup does not? Keydown behaves very oddly as you suggested. Currently working on solution with keydown that will have some sort of decent user experience!

Comment: I think, it is because by the time `keyup` is processed the pressed key is already added to the inputs value, so you cannot revert it

Answer (score 1):

`live` is depreciated and use `keypress`

```
$('body').delegate(".textarea-char-count","keypress", function(event) {
        MYAPP.COMMON.textareaCounter(this, event);
    });
```