# jQuery hide element by key press

Tags: jquery, keypress

I'm trying to hide all the buttons (or any other element I choose) by pressing the right arrow on my keyboard. Anyone know whats wrong?

```
$("body").keyPress(function(key){
    if (key.which == 39){
        $("button").hide();
    }
});
```

haha wow thanks

Comment: It's `.keypress()` and not `.keyPress()`. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: use .keydown() for all browser support

Answer (score 3):

its [keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), change:

```
$("body").keypress(function(key){
    if (key.which == 39){
        $("button").hide();
    }
});
```

Better to use [keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/), as:

1. keypress() will never be fired with Shift, Esc, and Delete &
2. keypress() in some browser will be triggered by arrow keys but its not cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) for detecting arrow keys(because [it is fired only for printable characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418562/why-isnt-backspace-being-detected-using-jquery-keypress-event#answer-4418596)), use [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead

```
$("body").keyup(function (key) {
    console.log(key.which)
    if (key.which == 39) {
        $("button").hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2Ej9s/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
```

instead of `KeyPress` , its arrow keys .

Check [jQuery keypress left/right navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104158/jquery-keypress-left-right-navigation)