# event.which and event.keycode is not working on internet explorer 10 for backspace button

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have to track the `alphabet keys` and `backspace key` with `JavaScript`.
I am using below written code to track every key press but unfortunately when i press `backspace button` in `IE` i  gets nothing any idea regarding the issue.

```
    $('#crossword').delegate('.grid_input_holder','keypress',function(event){
            alert('keycode : '+event.keycode+' which : '+$(this).val( String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript e.keyCode doesn't catch Backspace/Del in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084715/javascript-e-keycode-doesnt-catch-backspace-del-in-ie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to support IE and you use special keys (like `delete` and `backspace`) I suggest using `keydown`/`keyup` instead.

> **Special keys**
>
> Explorer **doesn't fire the keypress**
>   event for delete, end, enter, escape,
>   function keys, home, insert,
>   pageUp/Down and tab.
>
> If you need to detect these keys, do yourself a favour and search for their keyCode **onkeydown/up**, and ignore both onkeypress and charCode.

You can read more on cross browser issues of **[Detecting keystrokes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) *(Quirksmode)***.

OR

Key Code for Backspace will take the value = **83** *if we already have a few characters in a Text Box .*

The Key Code will be = **8** *if there are NO Characters in the Text Box and we are trying to Hit Backspace.*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support IE and you use special keys (like `delete` and `backspace`) I suggest using `keydown/keyup` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem araises when you are using IE10 . Because in the IE versions < 9 give

```
event.which == undefined || event.which == zero
```

when special handling key is pressed like **Backspace,DEL,INS,HOME,Navigation Keys, Enter, etc.**
So we could easily identify when a special handling character is pressed and can be handled seperately.

But in **IE10** . **event.which** doesn't give undefined or zero for special handling keys instead it gives keycode.... 
Surprising thing is , It gives same key code for Dot( . ) and Delete , Single quote( ' ) and Right arrow , etc.

Hence we couldn't identify exactly in IE10 when special handling key is pressed by using **neither 
event.which nor event.keycode** .

In such Situations ... Use

```
event.charCode == 0
```

For identifying special handling characters in **IE10**

Trust me friends, It saved me more than a week's effort.